# CKEDITOR 4.1: How to capture a new p element?

Tags: ckeditor

I am still very new to CKEDITOR.

Is there an event or a way to get notified whenever a new p element is created?

The p element is created when user presses enter.

I will need to access that p element so that I could insert a custom tag.

The CKEDITOR version is 4.1.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this (almost, but I assume we're sane). You can, however, easily append anything to your DOM structure when obtaining data from the editor by playing with [dataProcessor](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Data_Processor) (`editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules()`).

See some pieces ([sample#1](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/htmlwriter/samples/outputforflash.html#L175-L228), [sample#2](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/htmlwriter/samples/outputhtml.html#L160-L209)) of code to get the idea. You can modify children of elements as well.

Comment: Hmmm...I will take a look at this. Will share if I am able to figure it out. Thanks oleq.